# keep available a variable from alertdialog to main code

Tags: android

The code as example shows an alertdialog. I'd like put the choose of user to button1. I can't understand how pass the variable "arg1" to main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View view) { 

            alertSingleChoiceItems();

              }
            });
        // I need put here my variable:
        button1.setText(""+???);
    }

public void alertSingleChoiceItems(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
 builder.setTitle("Choose One")

    .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.choices, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

        }

    })
```

below is why the users have to click to ok to set the choose:

```
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
            showToast("selectedPosition: " + selectedPosition);
        }
    })

    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    })
    .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a public (not nessesary static) variable in your main class like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
         private Button button1;

         public int arg;
```

then:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
     arg = arg1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set the Button in your onClick of the Dialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Choose One");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.choices, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        button1.setText(""+arg1);
    }
});
builder.create().show();
```

You cannot set it as you suggest, because the code to set the Button text will have run before alertSingleChoiceItems(); is called.

Comment: Thank you! But I need use that variable inside main code :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a global static interger variable and assign the arg1 to it inside your button click...something like

```
private static int x = 0;

.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.choices, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
       x = arg1;
    }

})
```

Edit:

If you want to directly set the button text then Knossos's answer is mostly helpful than my answer..

Comment: The variable need not be static. As an addendum.

Comment: @Knossos Yes..you are right.. But static may work more friendly than the simple variable.Thanks for the suggestion :)